# Ubuntu can't connect to internet

Tags: ubuntu, internet, connection

Ubuntu is unable to connect to internet, both live CD and installed Ubuntu can't connect to network. The system sees the Ethernet interface from the look of `ifconfig` output:

```
*eth0
  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:04:4b:c4:bd  
  inet6 addr: fe80::23d:9ff:fe4b:c4bd/64 Scope:Link        
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
  RX packets:302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0   
  TX packets:343 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0      
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000        
  RX bytes:20208 (20.2 KB)  TX bytes:74524 (74.5 KB)         
  Interrupt:16

lo
  Link enc ap:Local Loopback      
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0        
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host         
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1         
  RX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0        
  TX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0         
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0        
  RX bytes:87621 (87.6 KB)  TX bytes:87621 (87.6 KB)*

dhclient eth0: 

*RTNETLINK answer: Operation not permitted*
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem would appear to be your computer does not have an IP address, and you are trying to invoke the dhclient to get it - **but you are not root**.  You need to be root to attain a DHCP lease (try sudo dhclient eth0)

Comment: sudo dhclient eth0: [1]2591 but no connection

Comment: What happens if you try and bring the link up with a static IP, for example using the commands  ifconfig eth0 X.X.X.X;  route add default gw X.X.X.Y

Comment: i configured static IP and get ping working, but browser can't find pages claiming DNS lookup failed.

Comment: Does DHCP work for other machines ?  It sounds to me like your DHCP server is not handing out DHCP leases.  The problem you have with the static IP address can be rectified by editing /etc/resolv.conf and adding a line "nameserver X.X.X.X" - of-course, the point of setting it up statically was to eliminate potential problems - we now know that your ethernet interface is working and connected to the Internet :>